# Any tool to generate class dependency graph from a solution

Tags: c#, .net

Have a solution, is there any tool to generate class map and their relationship?

Comment: I've asked a new version of this question again, on [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5649/1008).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can generate a [Dependency Graph](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx).

In the menu, go to:

***Architecture* > *Generate Dependecy Graph* > *By Class***

Here's an example of what it shows (in a very small project):

[image: Dependecy Graph]

And you can even see the dependecies between two classes. Take a look at the following image:

[image: Calls]

If you *expand* the class `Logger` and click on `Scraper`, you will see what methods are being called (in `Logger`) by `Scraper`.

In this moment I don't have an example of inheritance, but you can always create a project and test it yourself.

Comment: Just so that you guys know: "These graphs can only be created in Visual Studio Ultimate edition, but they can be viewed and navigated with read-only access in Visual Studio Premium." [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx]

Answer (score 8):

The dependency graph feature of VS2010 is pretty cool, but it requires VS2010 Ultimate. If you don't have it, I can highly recommand  [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com).

It will give you dependency graphs, and much, MUCH more. There's even an open source / academic license available (with some of the feaures cut out).

Comment: Actually the free versions i tried does not contain usable dependency graphs (the image it shows is watermarked and non zoomable so You will see only some kind of modern art painting when used on a reasonable sized project)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that (or forgot perhaps). I switched to the professional version some two or three years ago.

Comment: @ZFE now the trial version of NDepend is 100% featured, you can use all sorts of graph (call graph, cycle graph, inheritance graph, coupling graph, assemblies/namespace/class dependencies...) and also a dependency matrix can help demystify complex situations  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio then open "Solution Explorer". There you will find an icon named "View Class Diagram". Click there. This will generate class list only but not their relationship.
You must click on your project to view the icon. I added a screen shot. Look at circles:
[image]

Comment: It does add lines for inheritance, but not much else.

Comment: @Justin & user496949: Oscar Mederos shown an useful way. But if you need something simple you can use this method.

Comment: This is a class diagram and no dependency graph