# how to calculate class level dependencies from a C# class

Tags: c#, algorithm, dependencies

I have a class A which uses class B and C.
I want to write a program which will analyze the class level dependencies and will build a dependency graph.
In this case, program will give the output that A depends on B and C by reading.
So I want to know  is there any algorithm to achieve this ?

Comment: The algorithm would be a BFS; read about graph theory.  The hard part is a C# parser; you want Roslyn.

Comment: Or just use NDepends.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5101565/632337) as well.

Comment: Or just use Visual Studio, Architecture + Generate Dependency Graph.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't use the existing tool. I am willing to make a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tool like NDepend. Let's look at an example why:

```
public int somemethod(Stream s) {
    var z = new MyClass(s);
    return MyUtility.Calculate(z.Value);
}
```

If you use reflection, you can get the return type of the method and the types of the parameters (MethodInfo, ParameterInfo). But you see, a class can use other stuff (MyClass, MyUtility) inside its body, and reflection doesn't give you that information. Well, it does, in the form of binary IL code (GetMethodBody), but that's as far as it goes. It takes a lot of effort to decompile and analyze that. You could be tempted to go a bit further, because MethodBody allows you to analyze the local variables, but that still won't give you everything you need. In order to find all dependencies, you need to decompile the IL code.

So you shouldn't just jump on this problem because it is very complex but already solved many times.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I am looking to create my own tool. That's why I want to how this dependency graph is generated by these tools. As you said, one approach is to IL. Likewise, I want to explore the additional ways.

Comment: What other ways? The information you need is in the IL, so you need to decompile the IL, there is no other way. Some of the big tools, like NDepend, let you use them as a library, so they do the heavy lifting and you can write your own app around them. A more low-level solution could be the Mono.Cecil library. I think it is only a decompiler, and you can write the rest. But I really don't think you want to write another decompiler yourself from scratch.

Comment: To develop a bit on NDepend, you can first look at default code queries http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html    They are LINQ queries based on NDepend.CodeModel types. These types are defined in NDepend.API. For more complex scenarios you can write a .NET program that uses NDepend.API. http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html     NDepend.CodeModel types contain everything you need to browse the code dependency graph.  (Disclaimer: I work in the NDepend team)

Comment: @fejesco: you are write I am looking to write a decompiler for my own, Instead I was looking for what can be the possible solutions to approach this problem. As suggested by Patrick, I would try to exlpore NDepend API.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I would surely try this API. I think it will work for me